# Why does adding bound to a TypeVar make mypy not recognize this Protocol?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

The assignment within `func()` below doesn't typecheck:

```py
from typing import Generic, Protocol, TypeVar
T = TypeVar("T")
V = TypeVar("V")
K = TypeVar("K", bound=int)

class Gen(Generic[T, K]):
    ...

class Foo(Protocol[T]):
    def g(self, t: Gen[T, K]) -> T:
        ...

class Bar(Generic[T]):
    def g(self, t: Gen[T, K]) -> T:
        raise RuntimeError

def func(v: V) -> None:
    x: Foo[V] = Bar[V]()
```

*However*, if we remove the `bound=int` from the TypeVar, it does. What's going on here?

Comment: I don't know, but in your example, there's no point in the typevar `K` in either `g`, you may as well make them `int`. This may be why it's not type-checking, but I don't understand the mechanics of floating typevars well enough to be sure

Comment: This looks like a mypy bug; pyright type-checks this properly.

Comment: @joel this example is a bit artificial, but imagine the return type of `g` was `K` not `T` and you had two subclasses of `int`, `XInt` and `YInt`. You might need to distinguish between them later. I think this is a [bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/16125).